# Sprite Action Jump Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

How would I make my sprite `dino` jump? I have a physics world set up

```
_physicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
_physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0, 0);
_physicsWorld.debugDraw = NO;
_physicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;
[self addChild:_physicsWorld];
```

I was thinking that I could applyForce to make the sprite jump but that will only shoot it up, this is where i am using the physics world to make the sprite move up

```
- (void)onJButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
CGPoint force = ccpMult(ccp(0,90), 10); //x=0, y=90, force=600
[dino.physicsBody applyForce:force];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In space no one can jump. Unless they are on a planet that exerts a gravitational force.

```
_physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0, -9);
```

Tweak gravity as needed.

Comment: What could i do to make certain sprites not be affected by the gravitational force?

Comment: set affectedByGravity to NO https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/affectedByGravity